# Is there a trick to get an index.jsp file auto redirected to by Tomcat, to use the html cache manifest?

Tags: html, caching, tomcat, manifest, browser-cache

- I have a properly generated `cache.manifest` file.
- I have ensured that it is being served with the correct mimetype.
- I have an `index.jsp` file which correctly references the `cache.manifest` file.
- I have set up Tomcat so that if I hit `http://example.org/` it will load `index.jsp`
- When I hit `http://example.org/index.jsp`

  - The `cache.manifest` is read, processed and works! Chrome shows all of the caching events.
  - Repeated visits show the `Application Cache Checking event`, `Application Cache NoUpdate` events in Chrome
- When I hit `http://example.org/`

  - The browser acts as if there is no `cache.manifest` at all!
  - There are not cache events sent to the Chrome console

Is there a trick to get an index.jsp file auto redirected to by Tomcat, to use the html cache manifest?